# Ignore \n in javascript string

Tags: javascript, backspace

i have a basic system to convert `\n` to `<br/>` but when i add `Hello\nhow are you` in the box from a variable, `\n` not is show, and this not have effect, only works when the user add `\n` in the textarea to show in preview box. how can ignore `\n` in js vars?

```
function convertirDialogo(val_, type) {
    val_ = val_.replace(/\\t/g, "<p class=\"create_t\"></p>");

    console.log(type);
    if (type !== 'DIALOG_STYLE_LIST') {
        val_ = val_.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < val_.length; i++) {
        var _list_created = false;
        if (type === 'DIALOG_STYLE_LIST') {
            var l_ = val_.charAt(i) == "\\" && val_.charAt(i + 1) == "n";
            if (i == 0 && l_ == false) {
                val_ = '<li>' + val_;
            } else {
                if (l_) {
                    val_ = val_.replace(/\\n/g, '<li>');
                }
            }
        }
        var start = i;
        var end = i + 7
        if (val_.charAt(start) == '{' && val_.charAt(end) == '}') {
            var _col = val_.substring(start, end + 1);
            var __col = _col.substring(1, _col.length - 1);

            val_ = val_.replace(_col, "<span style=\"color: #" + __col + ";\">");
        }
    }
    return val_;
}
```

example: http://image.prntscr.com/image/3312c7182fdf4e1d8a538c941c86bdf7.png

that works, but if i add button to add `\n` to textbox from js not works.

Comment: Please show, don't just describe, your code.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

That seems like a lot of work when you could simply add [`whitespace: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the CSS rules of wherever you're displaying the string.

Comment: Yes, it works but only in preview, not add \n in the textarea. i tried:  `$('#textlabel-input').keypress(function (e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            var _pos = $('#textlabel-input').prop("selectionStart");

            var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
            if(code == 13) 
            { 
                $('#textlabel-input').val( ($('#textlabel-input').val()) + '\n');

            }
        }
    })` but not add \n in the textarea

Comment: Have you tried escaping the '\n' in your code ? ( + '\\n' near the end)

Comment: Wait @Spitzer … is it a <textarea> or an <input type=text>?

Comment: textarea :P okay, if i add '&#92;' + '&#110;', the result is showing in the textarea (\n), but if i add "\n" in JS to add in textare from a button, not works.

Comment: Depends if you're trying to add one LF character or the litteral `\n` sequence, in which case you should escape it in your code as `\\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following html to help you understand what happens.  In the example below, var a is two words separated by a new line character.  Var b has all of the new lines replaced by xyzzy surrounded by spaces.  Var c has all of the new lines replaced by 
.

If you just write the strings into the document, <br /> is recognized in both reformatted and non-reformatted text.  In non-formatted task, the new line is converted to a space and doesn't appear.  However, in formatted text, the new line does cause a new line since spacing and line breaks are preserved.

Now we go to the input box of type text.  The new line is a non-printing character and doesn't show up.  The <br /> is just viewed as another piece of text and does not undergo special processing.

Next we go to the texture element.  This element doesn't process HTML options, so the <br /> is just viewed as another piece of text.  However, the new line character is used to represent a line break in the textarea element.

If you want to remove the new line characters, just replace them with an empty string in the same way that it was replaced by <br />.  You can't really ignore the new line characters.  You just have to realize how they are processed by the various elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta encoding="UTF-8" />
<title>Javascript replace function</title>
<script>
    var a = "first\nsecond";
    var b = a.replace(/\n/, " xyzzy ");
    var c = a.replace(/\n/, "<br />");
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>This is a statement to study the Javascript replace function
      with new line characters</p>
   <ul>
      <li>Value a is the string first\nsecond (\n is a new line character)</li>
      <li>Value b has all of the new lines replaced by xyzzy surrounded by spaces</li>
      <li>Value c has all of the new lines replaced by &lt;br /&gt;</li>
   </ul>
<script>
   var a;
   var b;
   var c;
   function starter() {
      var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
      var area1 = document.getElementById("area1");
      var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
      var area2 = document.getElementById("area2");
      var text3 = document.getElementById("text3");
      var area3 = document.getElementById("area3");
      text1.value = a;
      area1.value = a;
      text2.value = b;
      area2.value = b;
      text3.value = c;
      area3.value = c;
   }
   function list() {
      document.writeln("<li>Value a " + a + "</li>");
      document.writeln("<li>Value b " + b + "</li>");
      document.writeln("<li>Value c " + c + " </li>");
   }
   window.onload = starter;
</script>
<p>Using Javscript to display variables</p>
<ul>
<script>
   list();
</script>
</ul>
<p>Working with preformatted text</p>
<pre><ul>
<script>
   list();
</script>
</ul></pre>
<form>
   <p>A <input type = "text1" id = "text1" /></p>
   <p>A <textarea id="area1"></textarea> </p>
   <p>B <input type = "text" id = "text2" /></p>
   <p>B <textarea id="area2"></textarea> </p>
   <p>C <input type = "text" id = "text3" /></p>
   <p>C <textarea id="area3"></textarea> </p>
</form>
<script>
   var test1 = /\n/;
   document.writeln("<li>A " + test1.test(a) + "</li>");
   document.writeln("<li>B " + test1.test(b) + "</li>");
   document.writeln("<li>C " + test1.test(c) + "</li>");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `\n` in a JavaScript string literal, it represents a newline character, not a backslash followed by `n`. If you want a backslash followed by `n`, you have to escape the backslash character with another backslash character. That is, you have to put `\\n` in the string literal.

You can use the following code to place `\n` in the textarea when the user presses the `Enter` key:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function replaceTextareaSelection(textarea, replacement) {
    var text = textarea.value,
      selectionStart = textarea.selectionStart,
      selectionEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;
    textarea.value = text.slice(0, selectionStart) + replacement + text.slice(selectionEnd);
    var selectionIndex = selectionStart + replacement.length;
    textarea.setSelectionRange(selectionIndex, selectionIndex);
  }

  $('#textlabel-input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      replaceTextareaSelection(this, '\\n');
    }
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cb2a4tz/)

This also handles the case where the user has selected text in the textarea and presses the `Enter` key. To test this, enter `abcdefghi` in the textarea in the jsfiddle and select `def`. Then press the `Enter` key. The value of the textarea will change to `abc\nghi`, and the caret will be just after the `n`.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a regex on the string to achieve this:

```
 var patt1 = /\n/g;
 str.replace(patt1, '<br/>');
```

It will replace all newline delimiters.

Here in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze8pLw03/1/) Using a text area element

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Yes, but if i add this:

`$('#input-label-preview').html(convertirDialogo('{8db0cd}¡Propiedad en venta!\n{ffffff}Zona: {dfde96}Idlewood\n\nIngresa {dfde96}/comprar casa {ffffff}para adquirir esta propiedad.\nPresiona {dfde96}"N" {ffffff}para obtener mas informacion.'));`

"\n" not appear, and that code not works